# Version of javamail included in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

Some classes of *JavaMail* are included in *appengine-api-1.0-sdk* jar (javax.mail), but not all. I need to add some more classes from *JavaMail* (e.g. com.sun.mail.imap). When adding *JavaMail* version 1.5.6 I get compatibility issues. When adding *JavaMail* version 1.4.7 things seem to work fine so far.

What exact version of *JavaMail* is included in Google App Engine version 1.9.38 (or newer)? How can I find out on my own?

When prioritizing *JavaMail* jar over the *Google App Engine* jars, I get security exceptions. Is there any trick to use a newer *JavaMail* than included in *Google App Engine*? Does *JavaMail* in *Google App Engine* ever gets updated? It's sad to miss features and bugfixes of newer versions.

Comment: Exactly what security exceptions do you get?

Comment: [From what I recall](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6718) it is spec 1.4. but I'm not sure if any of the service providers are present from the official JavaMail jar. Have you tried printing or logging the result of `javax.mail.Session.class.getPackage().toString()` to determine the version?

Comment: @Bill Shannon: I now notice it's only with JavaMail version 1.5.6, not with 1.4.7: It's:  
"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setFactory")"  
[http://pastebin.ca/3708998](http://pastebin.ca/3708998)  
I considered this reasonable, since Google App Engine is a restricted environment and this is about sockets, so socket-related parts could be implemented differently. This does not explan, however, why I could not observe it when replacing with JavaMail 1.4.7.

Comment: @jmehrens: For Google App Engine only it's just "### package javax.mail". When replacing with 1.4.7 I get "### package javax.mail, JavaMail(TM) API Design Specification, version 1.4" and when replacing with 1.5.6 it's "### package javax.mail, JavaMail(TM) API Design Specification, version 1.5".

Comment: @xberger Here is another example to try to determine versions:`Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.from", "one four four@or.newer");
        Session s = Session.getInstance(props);
        for (javax.mail.Provider p : s.getProviders()) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
        new MimeMessage(s).setFrom(); //NPE if less than 1.4.4 otherwise MessagingException`

Comment: @jmehrens: I got MessagingException. Btw I see every protocol doubled up in the service providers, maybe that's just the consequence of having JavaMail twice in the system?
Anyway, up to now adding 1.4.7 seems to work fine, so I'll stick with that. The biggest drawback is that I didn't find any substitution for JavaMail 1.5's _IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE_ in 1.4 so far.

Comment: @xberger: if you change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance you should avoid the security exception.

Comment: @xberger  My comment is wrong with regard to MessagingException. 1.4.4 and newer includes a cause exception.  1.4.3 and older includes no cause.

Comment: @BillShannon: That does work get 1.5.6 going (at least local). I was warned about getDefaultInstance in the FAQ, but somehow it sneaked back in. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jmehrens: It includes a cause, so at least 1.4.4. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common ways are to enable debugging or read from the package.

```
Session s = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
s.setDebug(true); //Prints the version to System.out
System.out.println(Session.class.getPackage());
```

You can reference the [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) [CHANGES.txt](http://javamail.java.net/docs/CHANGES.txt), [Issue Tracker](http://kenai.com/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=javamail&order=Importance&limit=25) and [the repository](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/show) then look for bugs that have been fixed in each version.

For instance you can tell if it is [JavaMail 1.4.4](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/301) MimeMessage.setFrom has a chained cause:

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.from", "one four four@@or.newer");
    Session s = Session.getInstance(props);
    new MimeMessage(s).setFrom();
} catch (MessagingException me) {
    Throwable cause = me.getNextException();
    if (cause == null) {
        System.err.println("JavaMail 1.4.3 or older.");
    } else if (cause instanceof AddressException) {
        System.err.println("JavaMail 1.4.4 or newer.");
    } else {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[JavaMail 1.4.5](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/365) if MimeMessage.setRecipients(type, String) does accept null address:

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session s = Session.getInstance(props);
    new MimeMessage(s).setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, (String) null);
    System.err.println("JavaMail 1.4.5 or newer.");
} catch (NullPointerException me) {
    System.err.println("JavaMail 1.4.4 or older.");
}
```

[JavaMail 1.4.6](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/470) if it supports `java.util.logging`:

```
Session s = Session.getInstance(props);
Logger.getLogger("javax.mail").addHandler(new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        System.out.println(new SimpleFormatter().format(record));
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
});
s.setDebug(true);
```